# Mongodb onetoone accessing related data

Tags: mongodb

Given the following schemas:

```
Schemas.Book = new simpleSchema({
  "name": {
    type: String
  },
  "publisher: {
    type: Schemas.Publisher
  }
});

Schemas.Publisher = new simpleSchema({
   "name": {
     type: String
   }
});
```

If I do a find query on the Book schema, how can I return the one to one related Publisher please?

eg: `db.book.find({});` currently returns:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("objectid"), "name": "Book 1", "publisher": ObjectId("pubObjectId") }
```

I need to resolve the `publisher.name`. Hope that is clear enough.

Comment: show some sample data and show your expected end result

Answer (score 0):

Mongo doesn't provide JOIN operation, so you need to make it in your application. Something like:

```
var PublisherId = db.book.findOne({'name':'Book 1'})["publisher"]
var PublisherName= db.publisher.findOne({'_id': PublisherId })["name"]
```

Comment: Hi

Thank you for your replies. I was expecting, and hoping to form a resultset that included all of the Book object and it's related publisher name. Something like {"_id": BookObjectId, "Bookname", "PublisherName"}

Comment: And Petr, thank you. Is it possible to achieve that using transform? so that all queries on books resolve the appropriate publishers?

Comment: For example if I try to use a template helper:

    getPublisher: function() {
      return Publish.findOne({'_id': this._id});
    },

Where this._id is an instance of book returns nothing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you may use getPublisher: function() { return Publish.findOne({'_id': this.publisher}); }